# Nested attributes in Rails where they key is a column field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a Ruby on Rails project where I have a model which accepts nested attributes for another model. I am not receiving the input JSON from a standard form, but instead from a library which has a specific format.

Say my database looks like this:

```
user columns: id, name, country
user_setting columns: key, value, user_id
```

The input I receive looks like this:

```
{
  name: "name",
  country: "country",
  settings: {
     edit: true,
     autosave: false
  }
}
```

I can access the settings as the nested attributes by doing something like this:

```
alias_attribute :settings, :settings_attributes
```

But now the issue is that the settings field is being read as an array like `["edit", "true"]` which can't be saved to the database.

Is there any way to configure the model to accept this input and interpret the key as the `key` column and the value as the `value` column?

I've considered restructuring the entire input to match what Rails is expecting but that just seems like extra work (for me and the server) and is a bit messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not supported in the behavior of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, and AFAIK it cannot be configured to work that way. You could define a "virtual method" instead to accept a settings hash that manually sets the expected `accepts_nested_attributes_for` style:

```
def settings=(hash)
  self.settings_attributes = hash.map do |key, value|
    {
      id: user_settings.find_by(key: key)&.id # update any existing user_settings instead of duplicating
      key: key,
      value: value
    }
  end
end
```

This will mark the associated UserSetting records as dirty, which then is saved automatically since you've declared `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. There's a lot of magic going on here, so you may want to balance the cleverness/framework knowledge required with maintainability. Writing a "dumber" solution may be better in the long run.